# Refresh current user's role when changed in ASP.NET identity framework?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-identity, roleprovider

**Using VS 2013, standard MVC template, and the Identity provider framework**

The user is logged in, and I have:

```
//....
UserManager.AddToRole(User.Identity.GetUserId(), "Members");       # Line X
RedirectToAction("Index", "Members");
```

And the Members controller is as follows:

```
[Authorize(Roles="Members")]
public class MembersController : Controller
{
    // GET: Members
    public ActionResult Index()
    {
        return View();
    }
}
```

After Line X is executed, I can confirm that the user is added to the table `dbo.AspNetUserRoles`.  However, the user upon reaching the Members controller fails the role check.  `User.IsInRole("Members")` returns false.

If the user logs off and then logs in again, then access to the Members controller will go through, ie `User.IsInRole("Members")` now returns true.

Is there some caching? Why the delay? How do I overcome it?

I also tried converting the method at Line X to an async method and used `UserManager.AddToRoleAsync`. The same delayed effect is still there.

Answer (score 30, accepted):

The identity information(roles,claims) are put into the cookie when the user logs in. Since the user is already logged in, this line of code `UserManager.AddToRole(User.Identity.GetUserId(), "Members")` will update the db , but not the cookie. You have to have to re-issue the cookie.

Try add `SignInManager.SignIn(user, false, false);` (if you dont have user, `var user = UserManager.FindById(User.Identity.GetUserId())`) before `RedirectToAction("Index", "Members");`

Comment: This should actually be something that should be explained for the Role.AddUserToRole() method. Or a "Caution!" box in the documentation.

Comment: 1 question: Mostly roles are assigned by someone else, is there an easy way using Identity to sent a sort of notification to the user to refresh his cookie?

Comment: If We need to implement a role based subscription in our site ( ie..user purchase a subscription we need to show extra presages without login)  this will use full @CularBytes.

Answer (score 0):

There is a problem with the @tmg's accepted answer.

`SignInManager.SignInAsync(user)` only updates cookies of the user who assigns a role, not the user assigned to a role.

If you want cookies of that user to be updated, you must somehow achieve to make `SignInAsync` command executed by that user. Like placing the command to the home page.

No need to say this is not a definite solution.