# How to update user role in MVC

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-identity

I used the "AddToRole" that add a user to a role. However this change cannot be applied immediately, this user has to sign out and sign in to apply.

So how to update this change immediately?

Thank you!

Comment: possible duplicate http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29285406/refresh-current-users-role-when-changed-in-asp-net-identity-framework/29286361

Comment: Thanks! But your one is for the current user. My problem is for the not current user.

Comment: if it not for current user, then it the role will be mapped user immediately

Comment: But the user that was changed the role still can access or cannot access 
specific action before sigin in again. And use "IsInRole" still return false.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If you use ASP.Net Identity 2.0, this is where the SecurityStamp comes to rescue! Calling UpdateSecurityStampAsync will invalidate the user's cookie and refresh its roles:

```
UserManager.UpdateSecurityStampAsync(userId);
```

More info: [What is ASP.NET Identity's IUserSecurityStampStore<TUser> interface?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19487322/what-is-asp-net-identitys-iusersecuritystampstoretuser-interface)

Comment: I think so, especially when the userId is the one from the current user ;-)

Comment: I was not able to make it work. In the second request current user still have the same Roles as he had during the first one. I have to use the SignInManager.SingIn() method.

Comment: Hmm, then it might be solved by this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24286489/how-do-i-forcefully-propagate-role-changes-to-users-with-asp-net-identity-2-0-1

Comment: It's interesting. Thank you!