# How to refresh Users's role in User.Identity - relogin doesn't work

Tags: c#, asp.net, model-view-controller

When Admin changes user's role, the database gets immediatelly updated, but the `User.IsInRole` uses the old role. The only thing that refreshes it is complete restart of the application.

I don't use owin, just FormsAuthentification.

Comment: what authentication method are you using? Identity? WebSecurity?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Refresh current user's role when changed in ASP.NET identity framework?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29285406/refresh-current-users-role-when-changed-in-asp-net-identity-framework)