# ASP.NET Core 2.0 Identity update user roles only after re-authorization

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, asp.net-core-identity

I`m using ASP.NET Core 2.0 with Identity authorization. When I change user roles through my data context, the changes take effect only when the user logout and login again. Can I somehow update them without re-authorization? Can there be a way to do this using managers?

Comment: Check this answer https://stackoverflow.com/a/29286361/3134112

Comment: Also be aware that 30 minutes is the default timespan for the cookie to be rechecked against the security stamp for the user.

Comment: And there is no way to force update immediately?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I asked MS about this, and it does not seem to be possible to update/refresh another user, only current. Se [GitHub Issue here](https://github.com/aspnet/Identity/issues/1831).