# Updating a user role with identity in .net core without relogging

Tags: .net, asp.net-core, asp.net-identity

I'm updating the role of a user with the following code :

```
string UserID = User.FindFirstValue(ClaimTypes.NameIdentifier);
                var user = await _userManager.FindByIdAsync(UserID);
                
                var roles = await _userManager.GetRolesAsync(user);

                if (User.IsInRole(Roles.niveau1.ToString()))
                {
                    List<string> lstRolesASupprimer = new() { Roles.niveau1.ToString() };
                    List<string> lstRolesAAjouter = new() { Roles.niveau2.ToString() };
                    var result = await _userManager.RemoveFromRolesAsync(user, lstRolesASupprimer);
                    result = await _userManager.AddToRolesAsync(user, lstRolesAAjouter);
                }
```

The problem is that the user must disconnect and reconnect to activate the new role. Is it possible to change the user role immediatly ?

Thanks

Comment: There is a problem with the accepted answer. See https://stackoverflow.com/a/77652028/13585203

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The identity information(roles,claims) are put into the cookie when the user logs in. Since the user is already logged in, this line of code `_userManager.AddToRolesAsync(user, lstRolesAAjouter)` will update the db , but not the cookie. You have to have to re-issue the cookie.

Try add

```
SignInManager.SignIn(user, false, false);
```

after

```
result = await _userManager.AddToRolesAsync(user, lstRolesAAjouter);
```

Answer (score 1):

@Hossein's answer works, but it comes with a problem. When you force a manual Sign-In, you have to hard-code the cookie persistency (whether the user will be remembered or not). This is a problem because this could cause users to be remembered against their will, or vice versa. It is possible to decrypt the cookie manually and conditionally call SignIn depending on user's current persistency choice, but it's an extremely painful process, and thankfully, SignInManager provides a convenient method for our exact purpose.

```
_signInManager.RefreshSignInAsync(user);
```

This will refresh the cookie with its current persistency setting, and the claims and roles of the user will get updated.